# Build of Keystone in Turborepo failed with error

Tags: node.js, next.js, turborepo, keystone

Building [turborepo](https://turbo.build/) with [keystonejs](https://keystonejs.com/) .

Steps:

```bash
// create turborepo
npx create-turbo@latest my-monorepo
cd my-monorepo

// add keystone to turborepo
cd apps
npm init keystone-app my-keystone-app

cd my-keystone-app
npm run build
```

Here is the build process stuck with following screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tDSv.png)

And then a bunch of errors ( should not be imported outside of pages/_document) for every model, ending like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPCCG.png)

How do I fix this error and let Keystone run inside turborepo?

I tried to move the keystone folder outside of `turborepo (the same folder),` and it worked fine. Build works.
But even the blank keystone inside `turborepo` becomes dead after node modules are installed.

node 18.18.0

"@keystone-6/auth": "^7.0.2",
"@keystone-6/core": "^5.7.2",
"@keystone-6/fields-document": "^8.0.2",

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. If you remove the redundant tags (which should not be in the title at all), it leaves *Build Bug*, which conveys nothing meaningful. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user who is skimming a list of search results will know what it contains. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].